# Getting 404 while trying to access endpoints using Jersey 3 and Tomcat 10

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, tomcat10

Been trying for days to fix this problem. Just trying to recreate a simple "Hello World" REST api with Jersey 3 and Tomcat 10 in maven. After creating the WAR file of the project I can access the index.jsp (created by default when I created the project) but when I try to access the "/helloworld" endpoint I get error 404.
Here's my code:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.security.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.security.enterprise-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>web-app</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

HelloWorldResource

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2010, 2020 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
 * terms of the Eclipse Distribution License v. 1.0, which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
 */

package jersey;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 *
 * @author Jakub Podlesak
 */
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    public static final String CLICHED_MESSAGE = "Hello World!";

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHello() {
        return CLICHED_MESSAGE;
    }

}
```

JaxRsApplication

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012, 2020 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
 * terms of the Eclipse Distribution License v. 1.0, which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
 */
package jersey;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 * JAX-RS Application class for this example.
 *
 * @author Martin Matula
 */
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {
    private final Set<Class<?>> classes;

    public JaxRsApplication() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> c = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        c.add(HelloWorldResource.class);
        classes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }
}
```

The error
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q9ce.png)

Using jdk 11, and I've tried deploying both in a Docker with Tomcat 10 and locally directly downloading the Tomcat Server into my PC.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jersey requires an appropriate container module to deploy the REST application. You added `jersey-container-jdk-http`, which works with a JDK Http Server (cf. [documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.javase)).

What you need instead is the `jersey-container-servlet` module (cf. [documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3)), which works in every Servlet 3.x environment. Therefore you need to add this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Remark**: Tomcat 10 is not a complete Jakarta EE 9 server, so you should also remove the `jakarta.jakartaee-web-api` dependency.

Comment: Oh thank you! Is now throwing error 500 saying there was an exception with the Servlet.init() but at least is not 404!

Comment: The error's stack trace is in the log. You can edit your question and add the full stack trace.

Comment: I faced that 500 error too. 
try commenting out the dependencies of jersey-servlet and jersey-client artifacts in pom.xml and restart the application server. After removing this dependency, the expectation is no exceptions should be prompted on Catalina log and 500 internal server error should be mitigated.

Comment: It's surprising how difficult it is to find some resources that can help it get up and running, thanks a lot for the question OP en the answer @PiotrP.Karwasz