# SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/demorest] threw load() exception

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, jersey, rest

I'm trying to run on tomcat 10.0 and these are the version I'm using

modelVersion 4.0.0
groupId com.telusko
artifactId demorest
packaging war
version 1.19.1
name demorest Jersey Webapp

I'm still getting the above issue and my Html page is showing HTTP status 404 along with ***The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.***

Below is my web.xml code

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.telusko</groupId>
   <artifactId>demorest</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>1.19.1</version>
   <name>demorest Jersey Webapp</name>

   <build>
       <finalName>demorest</finalName>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <inherited>true</inherited>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.6</source>
                   <target>1.6</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <!-- Run the application using "mvn embedded-glassfish:run" -->
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                   <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                   <app>/Users/apoorvabasavaradder/eclipse-workspace/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                   <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                   <port>8080</port>
               </configuration>
               <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                       <version>${project.version}</version>
                   </dependency>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                       <version>3.0.1</version>
                   </dependency>
               </dependencies>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
           <version>${jersey.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
           <version>${jersey.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>4.8.2</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
           <version>${jersey.version}</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
           <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
           <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.net.httpserver/http -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.net.httpserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>http</artifactId>
   <version>20070405</version>
</dependency>
       
   </dependencies>
   <properties>
       <jersey.version>1.19.1</jersey.version>
       <glassfish.version>3.1.1</glassfish.version>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: You are using incompatible versions of Tomcat and Jersey. See [Getting 404 while trying to access endpoints using Jersey 3 and Tomcat 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67970675/11748454) if you want to use Tomcat 10 or downgrade to Tomcat 9.

Comment: It did not work unfortunately