# Jersey 3 does not work with Tomcat 10 and return 404

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, http-status-code-404

I am having application that use Tomcat 10.
Java 17
My build System is Gradle.
I am trying to use Jersey 3 Servlet
My web.xml config:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>jakarta.jws.rs.application</param-name>
         <param-value>base.tests.war.logging</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

```
```

My class is basic for testing

```
package base.tests.war.logging;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/rest")
public class MainResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMain() {
        return "Main";
    }
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/commons")
    public Response getCommonsLogging() {
        org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(MainResource.class).info("Commons logging logger.");
        return Response.ok().entity("Commons logging!!!").build();
    }
}
```

My gradle dependencies for the jersey are:

```
providedCompile (
            // jersey dependencies
            [group: 'jakarta.ws.rs', name: 'rs-api', version: 3.1.0],

            [group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version:3.1.1 ],
            [group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-common', version:3.1.1 ],
            [group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version:3.1.1 ],
            [group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version:3.1.1 ],
            [group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject', name: 'jersey-hk2', version: 3.1.1],
            [group: 'org.glassfish.jakarta.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: 6.0.0],
            [group: 'org.objectweb.asm', name: 'asm', version: '3.1.0'],
)
```

I am putting the war file inside the correct directory workspace\webapps
I have another war there that is running correct.
But with the Jersey servlet it returns 404.

I have tried:
[Getting 404 while trying to access endpoints using Jersey 3 and Tomcat 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970675/getting-404-while-trying-to-access-endpoints-using-jersey-3-and-tomcat-10)

https://northcoder.com/post/jakarta-rest-jaxrs-on-tomcat-10/

Expect to connect to the URL inside the servlet.

Comment: You forgot to tell which URL you was expecting/using and which one appears in browser's address bar while facing the 404.

Comment: Read the following for how to correctly set up the application config (adjust to Jakarta where necessary) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625925/what-exactly-is-the-resourceconfig-class-in-jersey-2/45627178#45627178

Comment: I am trying to reach:
http://localhost:10010/war-logging-test-helper/rest/rest/commons/
war-logging-test-helper - the name of the war file
http://localhost:10010/error-test-helper
this one returns 500 
name of the war file error-test-helper

Comment: if you really use `<param-name>jakarta.jws.rs.application</param-name>` then it won't work

Comment: Issue was different,
for some reason my Gradle task for the war creation was not copying necessary jars inside lib folder.
I needed to change  providedCompile to implementation to make it work.